# Android studio giving us following error

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio showing error while compiling program. I have no Idea that is it a Android Studio Environment Issue or Windows Issue. I don't now why is Android Studio finding cmd in `C:\windows` except of `C:\windows\system32`.

Execution failed for task

```
':app:dexDebug'.
com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.1\dx.bat --dex --output
    C:\Users\Umar\AndroidStudioProjects\EchoDaily\app\build\dex\debug 
    C:\Users\Umar\AndroidStudioProjects\EchoDaily\app\build\classes\debug
    C:\Users\Umar\AndroidStudioProjects\EchoDaily\app\build\dependency-cache\debug 
    C:\Users\Umar\AndroidStudioProjects\EchoDaily\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\classes-56833bce4b6617d8545062aa1572a07084939734.jar
    C:\Users\Umar\AndroidStudioProjects\EchoDaily\app\build\pre-dexed\debug\support-v4-19.0.1-04dde37e48405b4442ed2e114457f34f6f27cab4.jar
Error Code:
    1
Output:
    'C:\windows\cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'C:\windows\cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    'C:\windows\cmd.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

here is my  `eacho %PATH%` output

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PC Connectivity Solution\;
C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\UleadSystems\MPEG;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\HMA! Pro VPN\bin
```

Comment: Run this command in your cmd and include the output in the question. `echo %PATH%` .

Comment: @pyus13 i have added my `echo %PATH%` output

Comment: I am in office and could not edit my Environment Variables to replicate the error but can you please try to remove extra semicolon in path variable after `DW LAN Card` restart AS after doing the change.

Comment: @pyus13 I have properly formatted output.

Comment: still facing that issue after downloading new version of AS

Comment: Doesn't seem like a Android Studio issue, something wrong with environment only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47400/discussion-between-pyus13-and-umar-abbas)

Answer (score 0):

I diagnosed Issue and solved it. This was Windows `CMD Sefault Path` Issue... i changed it in registry and my problem solved.
I removed key `default` with value `C:\windows\cmd.exe` in registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and Problem Resolved...

[image: This is my CMD image with i opened it using command cmd]