# Gradle Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' with new Android Studio Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I newly installed Android started a new default project.
Everytime I try to start the app this error occurs:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>   com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\iralu_000\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\Users\iralu_000\AndroidStudioProjects\BuyItOrNot\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\iralu_000\AndroidStudioProjects\BuyItOrNot\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\Users\iralu_000\AndroidStudioProjects\BuyItOrNot\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
>       Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
>       Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
>   (Englisch: The system can not find the path specified.)

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "iralution.buyitornot"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Installed via SDK Managers are:
[image]

I tried to clean the project via cmd with gradlew clean but the error remains.

I tried different JAVA SDKs (7 and currently 8).

I tried to add the support library to the dependencies as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18021901/android-studio-gradle-build-fails-execution-failed-for-task-dexdebug).

Android Studio is in Version 0.6.1

I have no clue what I could try now.

Thanks in advance,

Ira

**Update:**

I've manipulated the find_java.bat in the android-sdk which is called by the dx.bat. Instead of

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s') do set java_exe=%%a
```

and

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('"%~dps0\find_java.exe" -s -w') do set javaw_exe=%%a
```

I've set the java_exe and javaw_exe directly. This eradicates two of the three "could not find the path specified" errors, but one still remains and I cannot figure why.

[image]

Comment: I tried again with an installation on another drive (I thought it could may be an permission problem) but it did not worked

Comment: You could try Android Studio 0.8.1, the latest version - I know it's not the solution but might solve the problem, or if the problem persists you will know it's likely a project set-up issue rather than an IDE issue

Comment: As far as I can say it is a Windows specific error, because on Linux I have no problems with Android Studio. At this moment I'm running Android Studio 0.8.1 on Windows 8.1

Comment: I'm sure you've seen this but could the top answer here be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21102598/android-studio-unexpected-top-level-exception

Comment: ur gradle should be 1.10 and above

Comment: I had the same problem, deleting all the gradle cache directories did the trick

Comment: @Iralution it's not Windows specific, I'm getting this on Mac.

Comment: @Xerosigma at that time with that version I think it was a problem with my git installation. I used msysgit or something like that, which asks you in the installation process if you want to install custom behaviour to the cmd (like ls command etc.). After a new windows installation without installing that git-package the problem didn't occured

Comment: [This][1] works for me. It might work for you too.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27407125/1118886

Answer (score -2):

Hello i'm not sure if this will solve your problem but you should take a look at this answer

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/21752326

in this answer it seems that the `cmd.exe` command can't be found. And he solved it by making this change :

> I removed key **default** with value **C:\windows\cmd.exe** in registry at **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor** and Problem Resolved...

So maybe you should take a look at this registery to see if you could change the path of the command to fix this issue.

Answer (score -3):

I had this same issue. For me, the culprit was a cmd.exe AutoRun registry key, located at

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

I deleted this key, and the errors disappeared.

For more information, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx