# Android Studio Error 'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android

Hi I have just updated to the latest version of AS v1.00 release.

However when trying to run newly created project i get this error:

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       E:\Program Files (x86)\Android\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output C:\Users\Vilius\Desktop\AndroidProjects\voiceTest1\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\Users\Vilius\Desktop\AndroidProjects\voiceTest1\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug
>   Error Code:
>       255
>   Output:
>       'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>       operable program or batch file.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: The same here. Can you execute '.\android.bat' from your %ANDROID_SDK%\tools folder and post the output? I think the problem in '%ANDROID_SDK%\tools\lib\find_java.bat' which fails with:
"'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: I just need to know that you have the same output. This error interrupts my build process, I can't generate apk.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82388. Comment #33 in there has something which may help you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have encountered the same issue. As Mr. Blurred have said you should add `C:\Windows\System32` to your PATH environment variable. To do this you should open Control Panel, go to System -> Environment Variables, find PATH in System Variables and add the following entry at the beginning: `%SystemRoot%\system32;`

Comment: Doesn't this have the path to the JDK though? Or is JDK the lower case version of PATH?

Comment: @committedandroider, yes, it also usually contains the JDK path, but the problem is that the buildscript can't find and execute the reg command using command-line interpreter (cmd.exe). That's why you should add a path to system32 in that variable.

Comment: even if my machine is 64 bit operating system?

Comment: @committedandroider yes, it doesn't matter. Mine is also 64. It's a standard directory name in Windows.

Comment: so by changing to system32, that also includes the bin directory of the JDK? I remember in some Java installation guide that you have to set PATH to %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Comment: @committedandroider, the system PATH variable can contain a lot of different paths simultaneously, and all of them are listed there using ";" as a separator. It's normal. So it would contain both the system32 path and JDK path, and whatever else it needs to contain according to your previously installed software. As for this particular issue - it really needs the path to the cmd to be added there. The JDK path was always there in my case and it had nothing to do with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

i was also facing the same issue after updating to Android Studio 1.0. I spent like 10 hours trying to fix it but finally found [solution](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82112&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars). 
So I am going to paste the temporary solution here in case anyone is facing the same problem.

It seems the issue was not due to Android Studio or gradle . It was due to new **Android SDK Tools version 24.0.0** because it was working on computer's having **Android SDK Tools version 23.0.5**. So in order to solve it. Please follow this simple procedure:

```
   * Close Android Studio
   * Download http://goo.gl/v0UPm6
   * goto \sdk
   * rename 'tools' to 'tools1' (In case you need backup)
   * extract this zip to \sdk
   * it will make tools folder in \sdk
   * restart studio and errors will be gone
```

Credit goes to the person who figured it out. Thanks Man :)

Answer (score 0):

A patch has already been pushed to Android SDK Build tools. Version 24.0.1
Please update using SDK Manager.

Answer (score 0):

This will be resolved if you grab the latest SDK with tools v24.0.2, [which you can get here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#Other). This is actually a different problem from what was fixed in v24.0.1.

If you need fix yourself NOW and don't want to download a whole SDK, take a look at

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82388#c33

Additionally, a future patch of Android Studio will also resolve this. Sorry for any inconvenience already caused, however.

Answer (score 0):

It has amazingly worked for me. My mistake was that I set the path to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin
```

but after reading @committeandroidere I changed my path to

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin
```

and it worked.