# Cannot login to Appcelerator Studio (Windows)

Tags: appcelerator-studio

I cannot login to Appcelerator Studio. Tried different archived solutions from Appcelerator and followed their troubleshooting guides.

I am able to login with my ID and Password to the site but not with CLI nor Studio.

As soon as I double click the Studio Icon, I get this error in the log file, and get repeated login prompts (it doesn't even try to check user and password):

```
!SESSION 2016-06-04 08:53:57.697 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_91
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY com.aptana.core 4 0 2016-06-04 08:54:01.526
!MESSAGE (Build 4.6.0.1455770180) [ERROR]  null
!STACK 0
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.waitFor(Unknown Source)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processData(ProcessRunner.java:381)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processData(ProcessRunner.java:345)
    at com.aptana.core.util.ProcessRunner.processResult(ProcessRunner.java:432)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.core.internal.cli.NodeAppcCLI.runCommand(NodeAppcCLI.java:238)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler.verifyAppcWhoami(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1218)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler.access$4(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:1215)
    at com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp.handlers.TitaniumSplashHandler$3.run(TitaniumSplashHandler.java:303)

!ENTRY com.appcelerator.titanium.rcp 4 0 2016-06-04 08:54:01.541
!MESSAGE (Build 4.6.0.1455770180) [ERROR]  Failed to check login status. Likely not logged in.
```

I am deciding wether to buy a pro plan, but this is very annoying.

I run appc login -l trace and this is what I get:

```
$ appc login -l trace
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 5.3.0
Copyright (c) 2014-2016, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2016-06-06T13:47:43.450Z | TRACE  | set environment to {"registry":"https://soft
ware.appcelerator.com","security":"https://security.appcelerator.com","baseurl":
"https://platform.appcelerator.com"}
2016-06-06T13:47:43.466Z | TRACE  | executing command "login" with no plugins
2016-06-06T13:47:44.731Z | DEBUG  | Get username and password...
2016-06-06T13:47:44.731Z | INFO   | Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

? Appcelerator ID: perez.arroyo@gmail.com
? Password: *********
2016-06-06T13:48:18.852Z | DEBUG  | Get the registry...
2016-06-06T13:48:18.852Z | DEBUG  | Do login...
2016-06-06T13:48:18.867Z | TRACE  | running: reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\C
ryptography /v MachineGuid
2016-06-06T13:48:18.867Z | TRACE  | trying again, forcing it to use 64bit regist
ry view
2016-06-06T13:48:18.867Z | TRACE  | running: reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\C
ryptography /v MachineGuid /reg:64
2016-06-06T13:48:18.899Z | TRACE  | login returned { [Error: Command failed: C:\
Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography /
v MachineGuid /reg:64"
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query HKLM\\Software\\Microsof
t\\Cryptography /v MachineGuid /reg:64"' } undefined
2016-06-06T13:48:18.899Z | DEBUG  | body undefined
2016-06-06T13:48:18.899Z | DEBUG  | err { [Error: Command failed: C:\Windows\sys
tem32\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography /v MachineGu
id /reg:64"
'reg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /s /c "reg query HKLM\\Software\\Microsof
t\\Cryptography /v MachineGuid /reg:64"' }
2016-06-06T13:48:18.899Z | ERROR  | login failed, please try again

2016-06-06T13:48:18.899Z | DEBUG  | Get username and password...
2016-06-06T13:48:18.899Z | INFO   | Appcelerator Login required to continue ...

? Appcelerator ID:
```

Comment: Can you run `$ appc login -l trace` and see what is the error which it's throwing

Comment: Thanks for your advise Kondal... looks like some reg key is missing... what do you think? (I added the output to the main post)

Comment: Can you do what is suggested here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366895/android-studio-error-reg-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much!